# MySql query where to use more than 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I need to find the names of all the students who have enrolled in Course Operating system design but not in Database system design. So I wrote this query. Here the student is 1st table and enrolled is 2nd table with snum as foreign key.

```
select s.sname 
from student s, enrolled e 
where(s.snum=e.snum 
    AND e.cname="Operating System Design" 
    AND e.cname!="Database Systems"
    );
```

it is just printing the names for students enrolled in operating sys design and if its like it is just checking the first condition only.

Comment: You are going to need something more complex than just multiple WHERE conditions. This requires some form of subquery or left join to compare the results of teh `Operating System Design` results with separate `Database Systems` results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join properly the 2 tables, group by student and use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.id, s.sname 
FROM student s INNER JOIN enrolled e 
ON s.snum = e.snum  
GROUP BY s.id, s.sname
HAVING MAX(e.cname = 'Operating System Design') = 1
   AND MAX(e.cname = 'Database Systems') = 0
```

I use, the student's id both in the `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT`, just in case the column `sname` is not unique.
If it is unique, you can remove it.

You could also do t with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.sname 
FROM student s 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM enrolled e WHERE s.snum = e.snum AND e.cname = 'Operating System Design')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM enrolled e WHERE s.snum = e.snum AND e.cname = 'Database Systems')
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. Just want to ask, do I have to use this Max every time if I am using many conditions, or is there any other way also.

Comment: @HimanshuKaushik Use it once for each separate condition.

Comment: why there is 1 in select statement what does it signify.

Comment: @HimanshuKaushik 1 is nothing special, it could be 0, or null, or *. It is just a value that is returned if the conditions after WHERE are satisfied. If the conditions are not satisfied then nothing will be returned and EXISTS will be FALSE, or NOT EXISTS will be TRUE.

Comment: thank you sir for your time and solution. :)